# Download segmented SWF webpage

Tags: google-chrome, flash, download, safari

This has been doing my head in and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to download this SWF webpage.

It starts by loading story.swf then it makes calls to other SWF files as it goes along.

The flash itself is interactive this the need to call different segments a it loads the next 'slide'.

But I cannot figure out a way to download it for offline use. I tried loading the entire document which was 200mb and downloading the cache - no go. I tried to use extensions on chrome, Safari and Firefox - no avail

I really don't want to screen capture the entire file, but I was wondering if there were interactive flash file downloaders. I can see there are over 1000 files but cant download them

Comment: It might not be possible. If the Flash has (AS3) code to load the next segment from a specific server it will always need that server (not offline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @VC.One said, it is not possible due to the server needing to be present. It was constantly changing the string attached to the swf